# what are the steps do i need to follow , to migrate data from oracle database to AWS rds mysql?

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-web-services

I have an oracle database with different objects, like triggers, schemas functions etc inside it and i have a AWS rds with MYSQL database.

I want to migrate data from my oracle database to AWS-RDS MYSQL.

Is it possible to migrate data from oracle database to MYSQL database and if the data does migrate from oracle to mysql

- What are the steps do I have to follow for successful migration?
- And if the migration doesn’t happen to mysql which database in AWS RDS Should I go to??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to migrate Oracle database to AWS RDS MySQL database but you need to check DB_Engine, DB_Version and all the existing database configuration, which will help in tackling the compatibility issues while migrating. Also, use the same configurations in AWS MySQL database.

If you found any compatibility/Migration issues, then you can go with AWS Oracle database service instead of AWS MySQL database.

Please go through below steps before migration:

1. What is the size of your database?
2. Confirm the data and log file location for the target server
3. Collect the information about the Database properties
4. How many schemas and tables do you have?
5. Do you have engine-specific data types that won’t be migrated by your migration tool?
6. How busy is your source database?
7. What kind of users, roles, and permissions do you have on the source database?
8. When was the last time you vacuumed or compacted, your database?
9. Do you know what VPC and VPC security group you want to use in AWS?
10. Do you have enough bandwidth to move all your data?
11. Can you afford downtime? How much?
12. What happens to your application after the migration?
13. What is your contingency plan if things go wrong?

Steps for Database Migration:

1. Stop the application services.
2. Change the database to read-only mode.
3. Take the latest backup of all the databases involved in migration.
4. Restore the databases on the target server on the appropriate drives.
5. Cross check the database properties as per the database property script output, change the database properties as per the pre-migration- checklist.